# Python MRO in plain English

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

I'm new to Python and having troubles understanding Python MRO. Could somebody explain the question below as simple as possible?

Why this code throws *TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution*:

```
class A:
  def method(self):
    print("A.method() called")
 
class B:
  def method(self):
    print("B.method() called")
 
class C(A, B):
  pass
 
class D(B, C):
  pass
 
d = D()
d.method()
```

While this code works fine:

```
class A:
  def method(self):
    print("A.method() called")
 
class B:
  def method(self):
    print("B.method() called")
 
class C(A, B):
  pass
 
class D(C, B):
  pass
 
d = D()
d.method()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you resolve the hierarchy of the methods in your first example, you get

1. B.method
2. A.method
3. B.method

In the second example, you get

1. A.method
2. B.method
3. B.method

The first one doesn't work because it's inconsistent in regards to whether B.method comes before or after A.method.

Comment: thank you. I think I got confused by diagrams that illustrate Class relationships 'in parallel' while the Python's MRO is linear (I hope I got it right this time).

Comment: You're right but isn't the methods of a class searched in the order they are listed in the class definition, by this means whether D inherits C then B or inherits A then B then B (if we suppose we will not encounter class duplication Error) it should invoke the method in the A class